# Rails in-process background services

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a background job framework for rails kinda like backgroundrb that works in the mongrel process?

One could use it in small utility web applications to make application start easier and save memory.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use BackgrounDRb with Rails: http://backgroundrb.rubyforge.org/rails/

Comment: The tricky part is to run it in the same process as mongrel. I don't think this link shows that.